# Order of the probability of the "rarest" value found in a sequence of discrete i.i.d. random values.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\left(X_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. discrete random value with an infinite outcome space (examples: Geometric, Poisson, Negative Binomial). If we define the value with the lowest respective probability in a sequence of $n$ random values as $m_n$. Can I assume that for $n$ large enough that $\mathbb{P}(X_i = m_n|m_n) = O(\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're defining $m_n$. Can you give an example?

Comment: For the geometric distribution, the value with the lowest respective probability is the highest value found in the sequence. So in that case if we take $M_n = \max_n\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ we would have $m_n = M_n$. Though this does not hold for the Poisson distribution. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{P}(X\gt m)=1/m!$.
After $n=m!$ trials,there is a $1/e$ chance of no numbers above $m$, and expected $O(m)$ numbers equal to $m$.  So the expected count of the rarest number is $O(m)$, which is $O(\log (n) / \log \log (n))$.  It would have to be $O(1)$ for the probability to be $O(1/n)$.

Comment: That is a good example, thank you!  How did you get that $O(m)$ is $O(\log(n)/\log\log(n))$ though?

Comment: $\log(m!)$ is $O(m\log m)$ by Stirling's formula.  Then I need to divide by $\log m$.  Note that $\log(m\log m)$ is $O(\log m)$.